# Determine client OS in PHP

Tags: php

I have two pages redirection in my index.php. The pages are `example_system_os.php` and `example_mobile_os.php`.

How to determine the user's operating system in PHP?

Comment: Maybe a usefull info - you can test what browser is used based on the way JavaScript is executed. And there is a tiny possibility that this method is applicable for the OS, due to minor differences in the browser version on differnt OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`get_browser`](http://php.net/get_browser) function can be used to extract a couple of information the `User-Agent` HTTP header sent by the browser.

Amongst those informations, it seems there is some data about the operating system the browser's running on -- i.e. about the client OS.

Quoting the example given on the manual page of `get_browser` :

```
Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
```

But note that the User-Agent HTTP header is sent by the client, which means :

- It can be disabled
- It can be faked *(i.e. you can get any kind of garbage in it ^^ )*

Comment: i run this get browser function , i find one array  that is ismobiledevice , ut in my system it is just showing empty array...

Comment: i thing in my  mobile device it showing the 1

shall i use , something like when this array is one then redirect page to example_mobile_os.php

Answer (score 4):

You could parse the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` string for the various platform details, but I wouldn't be confident that this was a deterministic approach, since it can easily be faked.

Comment: or does not exist, e.g. when accessed via CLI